# Нагрузка на сервер

Tags: jquery

Имеется такой код на **jQuery**:

`setInterval(function(){
  $.post('ajax/check_session.php', {zapros:'zap'}, function(session_zap){
    if(session_zap == 'no'){      
      $('#session_false').show(500);
      $('#session_true').hide(500);
      $('#a_act').show(700);      
    }
    else{
      $('#session_false').hide(500);
      $('#session_true').show(500);
      $('#session_login').text(session_zap);
      $('#a_act').hide(700);      
    }
  });
},1000);`

Хотелось бы узнать, несет ли он большую нагрузку на сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Как для банальной задачи контроля завершения сессии слишком малый интервал опроса, и при большом числе клиентов - да, может давать ненужную нагрузку на сервер. Хотя бы 60-120 секунд.
2. Не понятно, как вы будете учитывать окончание сессии на сервере. При постоянном долблении сессия может быть гипотетически вечной.
3. setInterval - не есть гуд. Везде рекомендуется использовать setTimeout и создавать его повторно из себя же при необходимости.

Comment: ага, я понял, спасибо. У меня еще есть проверка на удаление сессии.